# SQL database login failed for Windows Sharepoint Services 3 with TFS 2010

Tags: sql-server-2008, team-foundation-server, sharepoint-services

I had to restore a TFS 2010 virtual machine and am having trouble getting WSS running. When I try to go to the Sharepoint Admin portal localhost:17012 it fails. In the event viewer I see a bunch of

> SQL database login failed. Addition error information from SQL Server is included below.
>
> Login failed for user 'TFS\TFSREPORTS'

TFS\TFSREPORTS is a local user (running in a workgroup not a domain). How can I re-establish this user as an appropriately permissioned user for WSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a login for the TFS\TFSREPORTS login into the SQL Instance, as well as correct the rights to the databases if needed.